# Allow user to select a row in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, vb.net-2010

I have a `GridView` which have 10 rows in it. The first five have data in them and the last five rows are empty. If user selects any of the first five rows, I'd like to mark it as selected, but if he selects any of the last five rows, then no row should be selected. How can I do something like this?

Comment: Is it fair to assume you're talking about `GridView`, the ASP.net control? I only ask because you haven't tagged this as such and because you make no references to javascript. Furthermore, what have you tried or researched so far in your quest to find the answer?

Comment: Sorry i am new here and add only those tags i know
And i am working in Vb.net i have tried this 
  Private Sub MyDataGrid_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles myDataGrid.CellClick

but this will not allow me to not select last five rows

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, so this may or may not be relevant. Have you tried just using checkboxes to deem "selected" rows, and disabling the five empty ones? Then you could have some sort of commit or next button that reads the selected rows and performs an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this event instead of Datagrid.CellClick

```
 Private Sub Row_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGrid.SelectionChanged
      // Do you code here what you want to do
 End Sub
```